# Passing character strings of different lengths to functions in Fortran

Tags: string, fortran, string-formatting, fortran90, subdirectory

I am using Fortran 90 with the gfortran compiler as part of cygwin.
I want to write a function that will create a series of new folders into a directory that is also passed as a parameter along with a number that is the maximum number of new consecutively numbered folders. Since I have to declare the length of the characters (ie strings) but also want to universally be able to pass different paths, I tried to pass the trimmed strings to the function.

```
program main

    implicit none
    character(len = 6) :: newdir
    character(len = 27) :: path
    newdir = "neu1A"
    path = "c:/users/i/desktop/rainer"
    print*,len_trim(path)                 !Outputs the correct length of 25
    print*,len_trim(newdir)               !Outputs the correct length of 5
    call newdirec(trim(newdir),trim(path),5)
end program main
```

But since I have to newly declare the parameters in the function, their length is overwritten/lost in the process. How can I use the correct length of the strings and keep the functional usable universally? I have to use the lengths because of the formatting string needed for building a string that calls onto the system to create the directories. I use Fortran 90, so a few options are not available.

```
function newdirec(newdir,path, foldnum)

    character (len = 27) :: path
    character (len = 50) :: newdir
    character (len = (len_trim(path) + len_trim(newdir))) :: newpath

    character (len = 100) :: format_string, newdir_len_str, makedir
    integer :: foldnum

    newpath = trim(path)//"/"//trim(newdir)
    print*,len_trim(newpath)      !Outputs the 'wrong' but declared length of 77
    write(newdir_len_str, "(I2)") len_trim(newpath)


    do i = 1, foldnum
        if (i < 10) then
            format_string = "(A"//trim(newdir_len_str)//",I1)"
        elseif (i < 100) then
            format_string = "(A"//trim(newdir_len_str)//",I2)"
        else
            format_string = "(A"//trim(newdir_len_str)//",I3)"
        endif
        write (makedir, format_string) "mkdir "//trim(newpath),i
        !call system(trim(makedir))
        print *, trim(makedir)
    end do
    return 
end function newdirec
```

Comment: Welcome. Please learn how to format your posts properly and use tag [tag:fortran] for all  Fortran questions. Note that the language is Fortran and Fortran 90 is just one old (30 years soon) version. Are you really required to keep your code strict Fortran 90? There are no Fortran 9 compilers around, all are *at least* Fortran 95 and most are fully or almost fully compliant Fortran 2003 or 2008.

Comment: I don't get why you make stuff so complicated. Why can't you use just `character(*)`?

Comment: Note: I think newpath should have a length of len_trim(path) + len_trim(newdir) + 1

Answer (score 5):

As Vladimir suggested, the normal way to declare character arguments of a subroutine or function is :

```
 function newdirec(newdir,path, foldnum)
    character (*) :: newdir,path
    ...
```

In that case, the intrinsic function LEN allows you to get the size of the strings inherited from the calling procedure.

I see absolutely no good reason to declare them with a fixed length like 27 or 50 ... except if you really look for troubles in a near future, for instance when you will change the declarations in the calling procedure : a length mismatch generally leads to a weird fatal error difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Vladimir, Albert and Francois I sorted out my problem as recommended:

```
subroutine newdirect(newdir, path, foldnum)

    character(*) :: path, newdir
    character (len = 1024) :: newpath, format_string, newdir_len_str, makedir
    integer :: foldnum

    newpath = trim(path) // "/" // trim(newdir)
    write(newdir_len_str, "(I3.3)") len_trim(newpath) + 6 ! +6 because of "mkdir "
    do i = 1, foldnum
        format_string = "(A" // trim(newdir_len_str) // ",I3.3)" !I3.3: Format for three-digit
        write (makedir, format_string) "mkdir " // trim(newpath), i
        call system(trim(makedir))
        print *, trim(makedir)
    end do
    return
end subroutine newdirect
```

Comment: Consider accepting an answer that solved the problem. That's how this site works if an answer is a solution to the problem it is marked as such.