# How can I create a function in Fortran, that reads from file and works with it

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have a bunch of files, which contain numbers in rows. I need to write a function, that

1. reads from file for the first time to find amount of elements in file;
2. allocates an array and reads numbers from file into array;
3. returns an array
   My function gets a string - name of the file - as an input.

So, the function that I wrote is:

```pascal
function arrays_proc(name) result(arr)
    character(len=128), intent(in)              :: name
    integer                                     :: i, tmp, ios
    character(len=30)                           :: line
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: arr

    open(unit=09, file=name, status='old', iostat=ios)
    if ( ios /= 0) stop "error opening file"
    tmp = 0

    do
        read(09, '(A)', iostat=ios) line
        if (ios /= 0) exit
        tmp = tmp + 1
    end do

    allocate(arr(tmp))

    rewind(09)
    do i=1, tmp
        read(09, '(A)') arr(i)
    end do
    close(09)
    return
end function arrays_proc
```

Then, in the main program I write

```pascal
...
real(8), dimension(:), allocatable  :: points, potent
points = arrays_proc(trim('carbon_mesh.txt'))
potent = arrays_proc(trim('carbon_pot.txt'))
...
```

When I run my program, I get instant "error opening file".
I assume the problem is with names of files or how I put them in my function.
Anyway, I hope someone can help me

Comment: I did not get the "error opening file" using your code. Are you sure that you supply the correct file name? Other thing: The read statement `read(09, '(A)') arr(i)` should use the correct format string, e.g. `read(09, *) arr(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling your code with a minimal `program`, GFortran prints the following warnings:

```
a.f90:4:25:

    4 |     points = arrays_proc(trim('carbon_mesh.txt'))
      |                         1
Warning: Character length of actual argument shorter than of dummy argument ‘name’ (15/128) at (1)
a.f90:5:25:

    5 |     potent = arrays_proc(trim('carbon_pot.txt'))
      |                         1
Warning: Character length of actual argument shorter than of dummy argument ‘name’ (14/128) at (1)
```

Trying to print the value of `name` inside `arrays_proc` shows that it is filled with garbage. So, guided by the warnings, you can try to change the length of the `name` parameter to `*`, which allows a string of any length to be used as input.

With that change, the function manages to open the files.

See also: [Passing character strings of different lengths to functions in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816383/passing-character-strings-of-different-lengths-to-functions-in-fortran)

Comment: In the line "character(len=128), intent(in)",   
len=128 should be  len=* .